# Update feuser in my extension

Tags: typo3

everybody) I need yours help. How I can update feuser in fillow file:

```
    <?php
    namespace Istar\Fefiles\Hooks;

    class DataHandler{

        public function processDatamap_afterDatabaseOperations(
            $status,
            $table,
            $recordUid,
            $fields,
            \TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler $parentObject
        ) {
               here must be updating code
            }

        }

}
```

I need update some user field.

May be I should firstly make instance of model and set field value? And then use userRepository? I don't know how to do it. Help me please. I would be very pleased if you can type code for my case ) Thank you for advice! )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
namespace Istar\Fefiles\Hooks;

class DataHandler{

    public function processDatamap_afterDatabaseOperations(
        $status,
        $table,
        $recordUid,
        $fields,
        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler $parentObject
    ) {
        if ($table === 'fe_users') {
            $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_UPDATEquery(
                $table,
                'uid = ' . intval($recordUid),
                array (
                    'ANY_FIELD_FROM_FEUSER_TABLE' => 'ANY_VALUE_FOR_ANY_FIELD_FROM_FEUSER_TABLE',
                )
            );
        }
    }
}
```

The array with ANY_FIELD_FROM_FEUSER_TABLE can also be the variable $fields which is of type array and contains all fields with current values you could adapt for your needs.